# A more efficient way to do this select and update loop

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table `votes`.

```
"id"    "votedElm"  "voteType"  "voteProcessed" "country"
"3"     "6"         "1"         "0"             "US"//1-1=0

"4"     "8"         "0"         "0"             "US"//2+0-1=1
"9"     "8"         "1"         "0"             "US"

"5"     "9"         "0"         "0"             "US"//2+0-1=1
"10"    "9"         "1"         "0"             "US"
```

and this my table `likes`

```
  "id"      "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes"
    6       10      3           US          1
    8       10      7           US          2
    9       10      7           US          2
```

I update the table `likes` by doing so in an event:

```
//Pseudocode - This actually is inside an mysql scheduled event
//Select all the votes
select id, votedElm, voteType, country from votes
if voteType = 0 then

update likes set votes=votes+1 where id=votedElm and country=country
update votes set voteProcessed = 1 where id = id

elseif voteType = 1 then

update likes set votes=votes-1 where id=votedElm and country=country
update votes set voteProcessed = 1 where id = id

End If
```

This whole things takes one row at a time. Do you see a better and more efficient way to do the sql here?

Heres the event:

```
BEGIN
     DECLARE vId INT(10) DEFAULT '0';
     DECLARE vElm INT(10) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE vType TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE vProcessed TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0';
    DECLARE vCountry VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE updateDone INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    -- declare cursor for employee email
    DEClARE updater CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id, votedElm, voteType, voteProcessed, country FROM votes;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET updateDone = TRUE;

    OPEN updater;

    doUpdate: LOOP

        FETCH updater INTO vId, vElm, vType, vProcessed, vCountry;

        IF updateDone THEN
            LEAVE doUpdate;
        END IF;

        -- update likes
        UPDATE likes
                INNER JOIN votes
                    ON votes.vElm = likes.id AND votes.vCountry = likes.country
                    SET
                    likes.votes = IF(votes.vType = 0,likes.votes+1,likes.votes-1),
                    votes.vId = 1;

    END LOOP doUpdate;

    CLOSE updater;

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE
    likes
INNER JOIN votes
    ON votes.votedElm = likes.id
    AND votes.country = likes.country
SET
    likes.votes = IF(votes.vote_type = 0,likes.votes+1,likes.votes-1),
    votes.voteProcessed = 1
WHERE
    votes.voteProcessed = 0
```

You can read more about multiple updates [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: I'm having a tuff time getting this to work inside my event. I'm all confused with the column names and variable name. Could u pls take a look at my event? I posted it in the question.

Comment: you are trying to execute this query for each row from `votes` table... but this query updates all rows that are needed , try executing it alone

Comment: or just remove the loop because you do not need it

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Is it possible to add a `where voteProcessed = 0` to the sql so it picks rows only where voteProcessed = 0? If its 1 then its already been processed. No need to process those.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do 3 updates:

```
update likes set votes=votes+1 where voteType = 0
update likes set votes=votes-1 where voteType = 1
update votes set voteProcessed = 1
```

Assumption here that you only have voteType=0,1 , so you process all.

Comment: @codedad assumption also that there are already entries in the likes table for all the possibilities in votes.votedElm and votes.country?

Comment: @Stephan: thx pointing to that fact ;) In this case I upvote your solution 'cos it is the right one!

Comment: @codedad thx :) for your query to work you just need to join with `votes` table

Comment: yes, later a realized this but if I do the modifiction the updates will look more complex than your solution ;) but not to mislead the readers I will change